# Error: The source report is based on a report type that is inaccessible to the dashboard's running user

Tags: reporting

I get this error while launching a Dashboard and trying to view the dashboard component related user logins by roles.

Error: The source report is based on a report type that is inaccessible to the dashboard's running user.

I know the solution from Salesforce is to give user's profile access to the object on which the reporting is done. But in my case, the object is User and I do not want to give user the permission of "Manage Users" simply put because they are normal standard users and not admin users.

Can anyone please advise of better solution for this issue?

Thanks,

Vimal

Answer (score 4):

My first thought:

1. check to see if the report type is "deployed" This is applicable if it's a custom report type the admin created

Failing that:

1. Change the running user of the dashboard. you can set the running user to always be someone who does have permission to view that data. For example - you! There's some downsides to this since any dashboard emails will look like it is coming from you. It also doesn't allow dynamic dashboards to be created.

This does get over the "I need users to see a dashboard but not see the data" issue.

Answer (score -2):

Give that permission to the running user, which can be anyone.

Comment: OP doesn't want to give that permission to the user..

Comment: My bad for not being clear. He doesn't need to give the permission to each user viewing the dashboard. He can set himself(system admin) or anyone else who SHOULD have that permission as the running of that dashboard. OP didn't specify if this is a dynamic dashboard or not but it looks like that.There is no way around giving a user the permission is just a matter of the type of dashboard you are using and to who you give the perm.